# Vue.js passing a variable through a modal

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vuex, routeparams, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to pass a variable from a Parent (page) component to a Child (modal) component. After reading a few examples, this works fine. The variable in question is brought in from another component as a route param. If i refresh the page, the variable is lost and can no longer be passed to the child. My question is, is the best way to persist this using the store, or is it possible to persist another way if the user refreshed? Any help would be appreciated

**Parent**

```
  <b-container>
    <Modal v-show="displayModal" @close="closeModal">
      <template v-slot:body>
        <ExpressionCreate v-show="displayModal" :lender-id="lenderId" @close="closeModal"/>
      </template>
    </Modal>
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5>{{this.lenderName}}</h5>
        <b-alert :show="this.loading" variant="info">Loading...</b-alert>
      </div>
      <b-btn block variant="success" @click="showCreateLenderModal">Add Expression</b-btn>

....


  created () {
    this.lenderId = this.$route.params.lenderId

...

    navigate () {
      router.go(-1)
    },
    showCreateLenderModal () {
      this.displayModal = true
    },
    toggleDisplayModal (isShow) {
      this.displayModal = isShow
    },
    async closeModal () {
      this.displayModal = false
    }
```

**Child**

```
   <label>lender id:</label>{{this.lenderId}}

...

  props: {
    lenderId: {
      type: Number
    }
  },
```

Comment: Use VueSession for persistence. A clueless moderator deleted my short to-the-point answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VueSession` to persist.

Simply persist your `lender_id` with

```
this.$session.set('lender_id', this.lender_id)
```

and you can get it later as

```
saved_lender = this.$session.get('lender_id')
if (saved_lender) {
    // handle saved case here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect for my use case, simple but effective

Answer (score 0):

You can use query params in URI by doing:

```
$route.push('/', { query: { param: 3123 } })
```

This will generate the URL `/?param=3123` and this will work after refresh. Or, you can use `vuex` and `vuex-localstorage` plugin, that let you persist data in the browser, and you can close the browser and open again and data will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the state of application to persist, I recommend that you use vuex to manage the state and use a library that abstracts the persisting to vue in a clean way. One popular library is vuex-persist. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

If you dont want to use a store, VueSession, a package linked [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-session) should do the trick

Comment: for some definition of "clean"